# Git workflow, rebase in cascade with 2 features branches

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am trying to find a good git workflow for a specific situation.

General case works fine: I have a master branch, from which I create a feature branch. I regularly rebase feature onto master, and once feature is ready, I do a pull request on master.

```
            master
            v
*---*---*---*
         \
          *--*
             ^
             feature
```

Now sometimes, several developpers are needed for a big feature.
We still create a feature branch from master, and then feature1 and feature2 from feature.
The workflow between feature1, feature2 and feature is the same as the one you would have with feature and master in the general case (sorry, my git drawing might be a bit ugly, not used to doing that).

```
            master      feature2
            v           v
*---*---*---*       *---*
         \         /
          *---*---*
              ^    \
        feature     *---*
                    ^
                    feature1
```

In an ideal world, once feature1 and feature2 are done, we would PR/merge them into feature, and then rebase feature onto master, and finally merge/do a PR of feature onto master.

But it might happen that we need to rebase feature onto master before that, to get some new changes or simply to not have to get too many changes at once. We might have conflicts that we fix (caused by an hypothetical feature3, or maybe because we already did a merge from feature1 onto feature even thought feature1 was not quite finished).

Feature1 and feature2 are not yet finished, and we will need to rebase them onto feature. And very similar conflicts than when we rebased feature onto master will arise. I heard recently about `git rerere` but I tried on a very simple example and I had very similar conflicts but not quite the same ones and so I had to resolve them all each time. I did not totally understood how it works however so maybe I did something wrong.

Another solution would be to not rebase feature onto master but rather to merge master into feature. So if conflicts are resolved there, they will not appear anymore when I rebase feature1 onto feature.
This pollutes the history of feature, but I guess I could do an interractive rebase to squash undesirable merge commits before merging feature into master.

So basically my question is: Is there a good practice for what I am trying to achieve ? My coworkers tend to just merge everything regardless, but I would like to have something cleaner and that I can understand from start to finish. Can I keep on rebasing and avoid recurring conflicts with `git rerere` ? Is it ok to rebase feature since it is a public/shared branch in this case ? Should I just not care about the state of feature until I decide to merge it into master and do some refactoring only then, merging master into it in the mean time ? Is rebasing feature onto master instead of merging master into it too much trouble for what it's worth ?

Comment: *Good practice* questions are off-topic by definition on stackoverflow, which is more about specific steps than about whether to *use* those steps at all. This particular workflow is not supported directly *by* Git though, and gets quite painful. I used to do it for some special cases I had, and wrote a (crappy) script that met (some of) my needs, but haven't needed it for 8+ years now.

Comment: All kinds of workflows are not supported by git in a manner that make them easy to do. You've picked one of those cases. Rebasing feature on top of master also means you will have to rebase feature1 and feature2 on top of feature, which may give you additional work. The opinion I have is that sub-features should be *small* and should be merged into the main feature branch before you start messing with rebasing or stuff on that feature branch.

Comment: @torek I haven't tried to define a workflow before, I agree that you don't necessarily have a _best_ practice per se, but I feel like some workflows are better than others, and that there are some consensuses.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ok so what you are saying is that I should only rebase feature on top of master when currents featuresX are done, and before creating any new featureX branches ?
Why is it better to first merge featureX into feature and then rebase feature on top of master than the other way around ? Both are fine as long as all existing featureX are totally finished if I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you generally do not merge merge to another branch, in this particular scenario, that would be the more practical option (as in "[merge master to a branch](https://superuser.com/a/224099/141)")

Rebasing a branch used by other branches gets tricky real fast, and the `rebase` operation is best reserved to branches not used by other branches.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it then practical to rework the history of feature before merging it into master and keep a clean linear history in master, or is it best avoided since feature was used by other branches, and we might need to go back to it if there's an issue ?

Comment: @PrOpoLo Once you are ready to include feature to master, yes. But not before because of the complexity of replaying the other branches based on feature. Once feature is integrated to master, you can do a rebase --onto in order to move the branch1 commits, and then branch2 commits on top of master.

Comment: @ VonC Once feature is ready to be merged into master, meaning all featureX branches have been merged into it, I rework the history of feature then merge it into master.
I would then only ever need the `rebase --onto` if I had to go back to feature1/2 to fix something. I would get the changes from master, since feature is not practicable after having rewritten its history. Since the history of feature1 is still based on the "old" feature, a mere rebase would yield a lot of work, while `--onto` would allow me to drop all the commits in feature1 still based on the old feature. Is that correct ?

Comment: @PrOpoLo I was only mentionning `rebase --onto` in case you are integrating to `master` the `feature` branch first, while `feat1` and `feat2` branches are still being developed.  But if you have integrated those to `feature`, then you don't need a `rebase ---onto` indeed.